# how to load extjs interface when using spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs4

I'm using **extjs 4 MVC** architecture and also i'm using **spring MVC**

When I run my project I can't see anything but when I use firebug inspect I see that all the js files are loaded

this is the error that I see in firebug

```
GET http://localhost:8080/Views/Ext4Example/view/login/LoginForm.js?_dc=1366793593142 404 (Not Found) ext-all.js:1
GET http://localhost:8080/Views/app/controller/Login.js?_dc=1366793593216 404 (Not Found) ext-all.js:1
GET http://localhost:8080/Views/Ext4Example/view/login/WestMenu.js?_dc=1366793593147 404 (Not Found) ext-all.js:1
GET http://localhost:8080/Views/Ext4Example/view/login/HomePage.js?_dc=1366793593141 404 (Not Found) ext-all.js:1
GET http://localhost:8080/Views/Ext4Example/model/Login.js?_dc=1366793593151 404 (Not Found) ext-all.js:1
GET http://localhost:8080/Views/app/view/Viewport.js?_dc=1366793593214 404 (Not Found) ext-all.js:1
GET http://localhost:8080/Views/Ext4Example/store/Login.js?_dc=1366793593151 404 (Not Found)
```

and also on the eclipse console I see

```
24 avr. 2013 10:31:40 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
ATTENTION: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Views/Ext4Example/view/login/LoginForm.js] in  
DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

and also I write the section of mapping

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"  location="/resources/" />
```

any one have a response?

Comment: The error seems to be that Spring MVC is trying to handle the URL request for '/Views/Ext4Example/view/login/LoginForm.js', but there is no RequestMapping for that URL pattern.  I think you need to add additional mvc:resources to exclude the folders containing your Ext4Example.  Keep in mind I have never used Ext 4, I am only basing my opinion on the error message.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use a different folder structure. In this case your resource mapping dosn't work.

give a try to following resource mapping.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/Views/**"  location="/Views/" />
```